Missing "package.xml" File During Android Project Setup in Unreal Engine 5
I am a beginner attempting to set up a simple Android project following an online tutorial. I have tried this process using Unreal Engine versions 5.3.2 and 5.5; however, I have encountered the same issue with both versions.
The error prompts me to accept the SDK license (see screenshot) and mentions a missing package.xml file, specifically expected under the directory:

Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Android\package.xml.

Upon inspection, I found that the file does not exist. Below is the output of the directory’s contents:
PS C:\ue\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Android> dir  

    Directory: C:\ue\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Android  

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name  
----                 -------------         ------ ----  
d-----        12/16/2024   5:48 PM                detex  

PS C:\ue\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Android>

It appears that something might have gone wrong with the installation, or this could be a bug with Unreal Engine 5. How to resolve this issue?

I should have mentioned earlier that I had all SDKs and NDKs installed, as I frequently work on Android development. However, the real solution was Vandit's final suggestion:
“Reinstall Android Support in UE: If the problem persists, consider reinstalling the Android support packages through Unreal Engine’s setup process.”
In summary, the key step is illustrated in the screenshot below.

Thank you for your assistance.

AI Answer

The issue you’re encountering is related to Unreal Engine’s Android SDK setup. Here’s how to resolve it:
Step 1: Install Android Studio and SDK Tools 


Download and Install Android Studio if you don’t have it already.
Open Android Studio and go to:


File > Settings (Windows) or Android Studio > Preferences (Mac).
Navigate to Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK.
Check the SDK Platforms Tab: Ensure that Android API level 30 (or the version you need) is installed.
Check the SDK Tools Tab:

Ensure the following are installed:

Android SDK Build-Tools
Android SDK Command-line Tools
Google USB Driver (if using a physical device)





Step 2: Accept SDK Licenses


Open a Command Prompt or Terminal.

Run:
sdkmanager --licenses

Accept all licenses.


Step 3: Set SDK and NDK Paths in Unreal Engine 


Open Unreal Engine and go to:
- Edit > Project Settings > Platforms > Android.
Scroll down to SDK Configuration and:

Set paths manually if they are not auto-detected:
SDK Location: C:\Users<YourUser>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
NDK Location: C:\Users<YourUser>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
Java Location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre



Step 4: Verify Project Settings 


Restart Unreal Engine.
Create a new Android project to ensure settings are correctly applied.

Additional Notes: 


Unreal Engine Bug Check: This could be a bug in versions 5.3.2 and 5.5. Ensure you’re using the latest versions.
Reinstall Android Support in UE: If the problem persists, consider reinstalling the Android support packages through Unreal Engine’s setup process.

These steps should resolve the SDK license and package.xml file error.

(To all those wondering I myself am not AI )...

Let me know if it works out.
